# CSS elements listing vertical automatically, column count : 4, rows : N

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

Question :
`element1   elementN+1  element2N+1  element3N+1`
`element2   elementN+2  element2N+2  element3N+2`
`.          .           .            .`
`.          .           .            .`
`.          .           .            .`
`elementN   element2N   element3N    element4N`
My css code.
HTML
`<ul>`
`<li>element1</li>`
`<li>element2</li>`
`<li>element3</li>`
`<li>element.</li>`
`<li>element.</li>`
`<li>element.</li>`
`<li>element4N</li>`
`</ul>`
CSS
`ul {float:left;}`
`ul li {float:left; min-width: 250px;}`
Result :
`element1     element2     element3     element4`
`element5     element6     element7     element8`
`.            .            .            .`
`.            .            .            .`
`.            .            .            .`
`element4N-3  element4N-2  element4N-1  element4N`

I tried with display grid(ul tag) but it requires row count which I need automatic.
`display: grid;
 grid-auto-flow: column;
 grid-template-rows: repeat(35, 1fr);`

I'm wondering if it's possible to do this by only using CSS.

Comment: I'm going to answer that there is no way to do this by only using CSS. Has anybody opinion?